# Object definition at top of client files in node.js

Tags: node.js

I am picking apart the demo code for this node.js game framework http://pomelo.netease.com/index.html.

all of the client js files in this folder,

https://github.com/NetEase/lordofpomelo/tree/master/web-server/public/js  ,

start with a line similar to this

"__resources__["/app.js"] = {meta: {mimetype: "application/javascript"}, data: function(exports, require, module,__filename, __dirname) { ... " .

Many of them (maybe even all of them) have an "exports." or "module.exports" at the end of the "data" method. I found that "__resources__" is defined in the .jshintrc files in an array as the "predef" property. Does it have something to do with jshint? Can't seem to search out anything specific about this. Just pointing me in the right direction would be a great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone wandering through here in the future.
I heard back from the Pomelo devs and they said this "This is our inner framework named colorbox ... it is a node.js style browser side module system derived from cocos2d-javascript"